# ExtJS 6.2 Sort grid Panel groupings based on summary row

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

I've been searching for hours to figure out how to do this. Essentially what I want to do is group data based on one column, create a summary for that grouping, then sort the groups based on the summary.

Using one of their kitchen sink examples, I would like to be able to sort these groups by summary value rate.

http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/examples/classic/grid/group-summary-grid.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using a *grouper* with a *sorterFn*.  The *sorterFn* should compare the summary values you are sorting by. For the kitchen sink example you mentioned, if you want to sort by the sum of the *estimate* column while grouping by the *project* column, the grouper would look like:

```
groupers: [{
    property: 'project',
    sorterFn: function(a,b) {

        var suma=0; store.each(function (rec) { suma += rec.data.project === a.data.project ? rec.data.estimate:0; });
        var sumb=0; store.each(function (rec) { sumb += rec.data.project === b.data.project ? rec.data.estimate:0; });

        if (suma > sumb) return 1;
        if (suma < sumb) return -1;
        return 0;
        }
}]
```

The grouper can be applied using:

```
store.group(store.groupers[0]);
```

See fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1im3

Comment: Sorting happening only in ascending direction is it ?

Comment: You can switch direction by changing the return values in the sorterFn (switch the 1 and the -1)

Comment: Ya. Got it. Thanks

Comment: I ended up using a tree grid instead, to be able to sort easily on many different columns, as well as ease some drag and drop features. But this would have been perfect for what I was doing with the groups.