# ExtJS 6 Sort grid Panel groupings by the summary rows

Tags: sorting, extjs, grouping, summary

My purpose consist in to do sort ascending / descending the groups by its summary instead of their raw data as usual.

There is another similar issue about this, but the solution that was given, doesn't fit what I need.
Using that same fiddle as an example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1im3, how can I do sort by the summary of 'Estimate' column, rearranging the grouped data by the 'Project' column?

Comment: Can you please provide link to the "similiar issue" and also post what have you tried so far?

Comment: Of course @Northys.
1º) The link to the "similiar issue": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40074010/extjs-6-2-sort-grid-panel-groupings-based-on-summary-row
2º) The same fiddle can be used for this, so I need to sort that grid panel by the results (summary rows). I'm trying to migrate from jQuery’s tablesorter to Ext JS’ GridPanel, but without success until now.